# Pass array from python to external express.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, arrays, express

In the backend, I have a python program(vmstats.py) that stores string data in vmonoff[]:

vmstats.py

```
import json
from proxys import ProxyServer

vmonoff = []

proxys = ProxyServer('XXXXXX','UUUUUU','PPPPPP')

for b in proxys.listeners:
    if "MYVMNAME" in b.vname:
        if b.stat=="UP":
            vmonoff.append('./images/vm_on.png')
        else:
            vmonoff.append('./images/vm_off.png')
        
        print('{:<10}'.format(b.vname), '{:<8}'.format('Status:'), '{:>6}'.format(b.stat))

response = json.dumps(vmonoff)
```

exec.controller.js

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname, '/index.html');

exports.executeReport = (req, res) => {
    execute("python3 ./src/vmstats.py", res);

}

var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

const execute = (command, res) => {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({result: `error: ${error.message}`});
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            res.send({result: `stderr: ${stderr}`});
            return;
        }
        createHtmlFile(stdout);
        res.sendFile(htmlFile);
        return;
    });
}

const createHtmlFile = (stdout) => {
    const rows = stdout.split('\n');
    const content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    <br>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>`

    fs.writeFileSync(htmlFile, content);
}
```

In the frontend(exec.controller.js), I tried to use:

var responseObject = JSON.parse(response)

But I got the `ReferenceError: response is not defined`

How can I transfer `vmonoff[]` from python to the external express.js?

Comment: @IgorBykov I added as a last line in python script(vmstats.py) print(response) and I still got the ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: well, that's because `response` doesn't exist in the global scope (by default, at least). Considering the `responseObject` isn't used anywhere, it seems like you can just drop it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems like your python script doesn't output anything to `stdout` (normally done with something like `print`), hence, Node JS have nothing to read from there.

Apart from that `rows` variable inside the `createHtmlFile` isn't used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

in the python script you need to print the array:

```
response = json.dumps(vmonoff)
print(response)
```

and in the node script, `stdout` is where you get the data, and there you can parse it and process it further:

```
const execute = (command, res) => {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({result: `error: ${error.message}`});
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            res.send({result: `stderr: ${stderr}`});
            return;
        }
        var responseObject = JSON.parse(stdout);
        createHtmlFile(responseObject);
        res.sendFile(htmlFile);
        return;
    });
}
```

and then in `createHtmlFile` you can construct the HTML (for example, iterating array elements, or maybe using `.join` instead of `.split`, it's not clear what the HTML is supposed to look like..)